# Proof of "triangle inequality" for outer measures: $\left|\mu^*(A) - \mu^*(B)\right| \le \mu^*(A \Delta B)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We use the following notation. $X$ is a set,  $\Omega_0$ is a ring of subsets of $X$, $\mu_0$ is a premeasure on $\Omega_0$, and $\mu^*$ is the associated outer measure, defined for subsets $A$ of $X$ by
$$\mu^*(A) = \inf\left\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_0(A_n) : (A_n) \subset \Omega_0, \ A\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right\}$$
with the convention that $\inf \varnothing = \infty$.

Let $A,B \subset X$. Then $A \subset (A\Delta B)\cup B$, so $\mu^*(A) \le \mu^*(A\Delta B) + \mu^*(B)$ by monotonicity and countable subadditivity of the outer measure. Similarly, $\mu^*(B) \le \mu^*(A\Delta B) + \mu^*(A)$. According to the book, this proves that 
$$\left|\mu^*(A) - \mu^*(B)\right| \le \mu^*(A \Delta B). \tag{$*$}$$
This is clear if $\mu^*(A) < \infty$ for every subset $A$ of $X$. However, this condition fails if there is a subset of $X$ which is not covered by a sequence in $\Omega_0$. How should the proof of ($*$) be completed?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the book doesn't include any finiteness hypotheses at all (look carefully!) then the book is simply wrong. If $\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(B)=\infty$ then $\mu^*(A)-\mu^*(B)$ is undefined.

It's true if $\mu^*(A)=\infty$ and $\mu^*(B)<\infty$, by the way. In that case $\mu^*(A)\le\mu^*(B)+\mu^*(A\Delta B)$ shows that $\mu^*(A\Delta B)=\infty$.

(It sounds like you're ok with the case where both are finite?)

Comment: Yes, I understand the argument except in the case $\mu^*(A) = \infty = \mu^*(B)$. The only hypothesis concerning finiteness is $\mu_0(\Omega_0) \subset [0,\infty)$, but I don't see how that helps. This result is quite important: it is used to prove that every premeasure extends to a complete measure. So I hope there is a way around the difficulty.